# How to get rid of "Delete Event" in the EKEventViewController

Tags: ios, uibutton, ekevent

I have a custom EKEventViewController and I can't find access to that big delete button at the bottom of the view.  I've tried searching through all the subviews to find it but to no avail.  Any Thoughts?

Comment: No one has anything?

Comment: you got answer? I have same problem

Comment: Nope I gave up and left it in :(